# How can I pass List in my method parameter?

Tags: java, list, arraylist, methods

Can someone explain how to define a List parameter such that i can pass a List to it. My method looks something like this. I need LIST to be replaced so the method recognizes "listname" as a list.

```
public static void function(int number, LIST listname) {
  for (int i = 0; i < listname.size(); ++i {
    System.out.print(listname.get(i) + ": ");
  }
  System.out.println(number);
}
```

In my main method I will call on the method as such:

```
List<String> myList = new ArrayList<String>();
  myList.add("item1");
  myList.add("item2");
  myList.add("item3");

function(4, myList);
```

Comment: I don't understand the question. Do you need to know what type to put in place of `LIST`? And what is the array of `double`s for?

Comment: @wakjah Yes. That is correct. I deleted some of my code just to make my question a little more to the point.

Comment: The type you need to replace `LIST` with is `List<String>` -- the same type that you already wrote in the calling code. Note that you also have a missing `)` on your for loop (though the parser should tell you this)

Comment: I think `List<?>` would work too, since all objects support `toString()`.

Comment: You've defined it as a List<String, so define it as that in your method signature and pass it in. And you can remove the String from the ArrayList. You can use diamond notation from Java 7 :)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Change the method definition to something as follows

```
public static void function(int number, List<String> listname) {
  for (int i = 0; i < listname.size(); ++i) {
    System.out.print(listname.get(i) + ": ");
  }
  System.out.println(number);
}
```

Comment: an enhanced for loop would be more idiomatic

Answer (score 1):

The Type should be a `List<String>` there is no standard LIST Type in Java (unless you make it ofcourse).